# Azure: How to createa a Access Control Service namespace for a Service Bus namespace?

Tags: azure

There're 2 kinds of authentication mechanism for Azure Service Bus:

- SAS : Shared Access Signature
- ACS : Access Control Service

According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170478.aspx),

> For all (Service Bus) namespaces that were created before August 2014, an
>   accompanying ACS namespace was created.

Now it is after Aug. 2014, so no accompanying ACS namespace will be created when you create a Service Bus namespace through Azure management portal.

The same link above also instructs to use the following Azure PowerShell cmd-let:

```
New-AzureSBNamespace YOUR_NAMESPACE –useAcs True
```

But [it turns out the `-useAcs` parameter doesn't exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495165.aspx).

So how to create ACS namcespace for a SB namespace?

Answer (score 3):

First off, are you using the latest version of the powershell cmdlets? A new version was published on 8/22.

There's been a bit of a kerfuffle and the updated powershell cmdlet hasn't yet been published. However, if you leave the new parameter off, the associated ACS namespace will be created automatically. I verified this myself just a few hours ago using the most recent (8/22/2014) version of the Azure Powershell cmdlets available via the web platform installer.

This said, the product team is encouraging the use of SAS over ACS.

Comment: Looks like the Azure Java library is not yet compatible with ACS: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/437

Comment: I believe its quite the opposite, the Java SDK does not support SAS, is required the ACS namespace which currently isn't created when you create a namespace from the portal.

Comment: You are right. I mixed the acronyms when writing the comment.

Comment: Can you connect using ACS from PHP?

Comment: ACS is being deprecated. You should look at Azure AD and its component solutions for any security needs in Azure.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I looked, there is no way to add ACS support to an already created SB.

What I did was delete the Service Bus, and create it again with Powershell. Also, it did not let me use the same SB name, so I had to set another name.

Before deleting it, make sure you have the structure exported, to avoid loosing filters, etc.

Here are the Azure PowerShell commands you'll need:

```
Add-AzureAccount
get-azuresubscription
select-azuresubscription <name of the subscription you need>
new-azuresbnamespace <name for the service bus> "North Europe" -CreateACSNamespace $true -NamespaceType Messaging
```

don't forget to import the structure back.