# Azure service bus ACS issuer and key is missing

Tags: azure, acs, azureservicebus, powershell-cmdlet, azure-servicebus-queues

I created some Service Buses today and besides having a specific type ("Messaging", my older buses are "Mixed") they don't give me any ACS information that I need. My old Service Buses do have this information.

What I understand from this: [Azure: How to createa a Access Control Service namespace for a Service Bus namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501453/azure-how-to-createa-a-access-control-service-namespace-for-a-service-bus-names)
is that I might need to use Powershell Cmdlet which I have no knowledge of.

Is there a way to add ACS to the Service Bus? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use PowerShell to create the SB Namespace with the ACS association. PowerShell isn't that hard to get used to. I'd recommend you start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554332.aspx